# transformar registo MySQL em variável php e mostrar no HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Eu estou pedindo para buscar no banco um resultado igual a uma variável url que já tenho, ele pesquisa direitinho, mas quero pegar outra coluna na mesma linha do url que ele foi buscar 
tipo isso:

| matricula | nome |

pesquisa por matricula, ao achar, pega o nome correspondente e coloca o resultado como o valor de uma variável. E me mostra no HTML. Me ajudem por favor :(

Essa é uma página HTML:

```
     <?php

        include ('conecta.php');

        $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$database);
         if (!$connection) {
         echo ("Servidor temporariamente fora de servi?o"); 
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM resultado"
        . "WHERE nu_mat LIKE ".$url."";

        $result =  mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if (!$result) {
          die("Query invalida na selecao dos dados");
        }

        while ($dados =  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

           $dados = ['nm_aluno'];
        }


        ?>
<BODY>
<?php 
         echo"<p class='texto'>"; echo"$dados"; echo"</p>";
         ?>
</BODY>
```

Comment: depois no html eu peço pra mostrar e não me mostra nada

Comment: o html não parece estar na pergunta.

Comment: `<?php 
      echo"<p class='texto'>"; echo"$dados"; echo"</p>";
      ?>`

Comment: editei a pregunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código `$dados = ['nm_aluno'];` pode ser inválido se estiver usando uma versão anterior a 5.4 do php e não vai fazer o que você está imaginando.

É feita uma atribuição(cria) de um array à `$dados` com o valor `nm_aluno`, lembresse que para acessar um array você deve especificar a variável(`$dados`) e qual a chave desejada(`nm_aluno`) com colchetes.

Essa instrução deve ficar dentro do while para ser executada N vezes

```
while ($dados =  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<p class='texto'>". $dados['nm_aluno'] ."</p>";
}
```

Quando tiver dúvidas de como usar um array pode usar as funções `print_r()` ou `var_dump()` para dar uma colada ;)

Comment: vlw vou testar!

Comment: @rray deu certo!

Comment: @rray obrigada!

Comment: @Bacco editei com a sugestão.

Comment: mas então vc tem outra resposta?

Comment: @Sarah como assim? antes do php5.4 vc só pode criar arrays assim `$var = array('nm_aluno', 'matricula');` do 5.4 p frente pode-se usar `$var = ['nm_aluno', 'matricula'];`

Comment: @Sarah a resposta está usando a sintaxe correta. O que estamos dizendo é que seu código tem uma sintaxe que o PHP 5.4 pra cima até aceitaria, mas de qualquer forma, mesmo aceitando a sintaxe, não serviria para sua necessidade. Isso que você escreveu serviria pra outro tipo de coisa completamente diferente do que você quer.

Comment: a então como seria para a minha necessidade?

Comment: vc estava criando um array novo a cada volta do while assim `$dados = ['nm_aluno'];` a sintaxe do que vc quer é `$dados['nm_aluno']` não tem sinal de igual :P

Comment: a ta entendi kkk

Comment: obrigada pessoal